# how can i disable save button for a form of field with same label but different ng-model angular js

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-directive

I'm a newbie. I have code something like this in  which has multiple same label(AGE) field (Though form has many other files too)but with different ng-model and name attribute. All i want is to keep the save button disabled until all the Age fields are entered.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Age</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" default="0" id="_AGE_1_" name="AGE_1" ng-model="AGE_1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Age</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" default="0" id="AGE_2_" name="_AGE_2" ng-model="AGE_2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Age</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" default="0" id="AGE_3_" name="_AGE_3" ng-model="AGE_3"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can i achieve that? Please Help

Comment: What about using a counter and a ngIf over the button?

Comment: You might want to include how you'd try to solve the problem, even if its just pseudo code. You'll likely get more people willing to help guide your attempt in the right direction.

Comment: witch version of angular you are using?

Comment: @BilalDjaghout angular 1

Comment: @arpit You already have the form validators! can you share your attempt, so I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using a simple counter?

```
activateSave() {
    return this.counter==3;
}

<button [disabled]="activateSave()" (click)="doSomething()">Save</button>
```